# Converting launch file from ROS 1 to ROS 2

Tags: ros2

I want to convert customize `move_base.launch` to `move_base.launch.py` in ROS 2. However, there seems to be issues of converting `LaunchConfiguration` to string. Example below:

From ROS 1:

```
<rosparam file="$(find ros_3d_multitb3)/params/costmap_common_params_waffle_pi.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap"/>
<rosparam file="$(find ros_3d_multitb3)/params/costmap_common_params_waffle_pi.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find ros_3d_multitb3)/params/local_costmap_params_$(arg namespace).yaml"  command="load"/>
<rosparam file="$(find ros_3d_multitb3)/params/global_costmap_params_$(arg namespace).yaml" command="load"/>
<rosparam file="$(find ros_multitb3)/params/local_costmap_params_$(arg namespace).yaml"  command="load" ns="global_costmap"/>
```

To ROS 2:

```
ros_3d_multitb3_dir = get_package_share_directory('ros_multitb3_3d')

# Move base node
move_base_node = Node(
    package='nav2_bringup',
    executable='bringup',
    name='move_base',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[
        get_package_share_directory('ros_multitb3_3d') + '/params/costmap_common_params_waffle_pi.yaml',
        get_package_share_directory('ros_multitb3_3d') + f'/params/local_costmap_params_{LaunchConfiguration("namespace")}.yaml'),
        get_package_share_directory('ros_multitb3_3d') + f'/params/global_costmap_params_{LaunchConfiguration("namespace")}.yaml',
        get_package_share_directory('ros_multitb3_3d') + f'/params/base_local_planner_teb_{LaunchConfiguration("namespace")}.yaml',
       get_package_share_directory('ros_multitb3_3d') + '/params/base_global_planner.yaml',
        get_package_share_directory('ros_multitb3_3d') + '/params/move_base_params.yaml'
    ],
    remappings=[
        ('robot_base_frame', f'/{LaunchConfiguration("namespace")}/base_footprint'),
        ('/map', f'/{LaunchConfiguration("namespace")}/map')
    ]
)
```

Is there any way to re-write the codes?

Comment: Missing ROS1 codes:     <rosparam file="$(find ros_3d_multitb3)/params/local_costmap_params_$(arg namespace).yaml"  command="load"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find ros_3d_multitb3)/params/global_costmap_params_$(arg namespace).yaml" command="load"/>
<!-- <rosparam file="$(find ros_multitb3)/params/local_costmap_params_$(arg namespace).yaml"  command="load" ns="global_costmap"/>

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I suggest going through [the official documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Creating-Launch-Files.html) and [demo codes](https://github.com/ros2/demos) as well.

Comment: I did go through the documentation but cannot find a satisfactory ans.

Comment: Please:

* Describe what you have already tried
* Where you found that
* What you expected to happen
* What actually happened (if it did not work)
* What do you believe the problem could be

Then we can help you.

Robotics Stack Exchange is not a place where we expect other people to just do your work for you. Of course, we help you try to get your work done, but we have to see a little effort on your side first.